# API backend versioning approach

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, api-versioning

We are using django rest framework for creation of apis(which are being consumed by mobile devices). We get the version from request.version in each requested views. All these apis are being used in scenario where requirement changes a lot over time. All the view internally call utils methods(in utils.py).

What is the best approach to manage the utils code as per version changes? If we assume number of version changes have been let say around 50.. that many number of if else would look very dirty ?

Also how to handle versioning cases if above utils methods are used across more than one django apps.

Any django package which solves use cases ?